# Analyzing optimizations made in assembly code

Tags: c, assembly

I am trying to understand how assembly optimization is performed on the following C code:

```
void rgbtocmyk(int r, int g, int b, int ret[]) {
  int c = 255 - r;
  int m = 255 - g;
  int y = 255 - b;
  int k = (c < m) ? (c < y ? c : y) : (m < y ? m : y);
  c -= k;  m -= k; y -= k;  
  ret[0] = c; ret[1] = m; ret[2] = y; ret[3] = k;
```

This generates the following assembly code (limited to the text portion), with no optimization on the left column and optimization level `-O1` on the right:

[image]
[image]

I am looking for some guidance on how to navigate through this obscure code. I am very new to assembly, and I've been wracking my brain trying to understand the differences. It is obviously more compact code with `-O1` optimization, with the majority of this compactness being the result of less `movl` statements.

Note: This is homework. The instructor has asked that I be as precise as possible in comparing the two versions.

Comment: Ask yourself, what does each sequence of code on the left hand side actually accomplish?  And, what does the code on the right side accomplish?  If they both end up with the same result, you want to run the optimized one.   So what unnecessary work does the left side do?

Comment: I'm working through the code right now, line by line. It's starting to make more sense now that I'm following it in sequence. Once I've solidified my answer, I'll edit my post to reflect my understanding.

Comment: You're doing the right thing. Understanding code usually requires staring at in detail for awhile.

Comment: I am afraid that SO is not the right framework for this, your "question" is much too broad to be searchable. If you have a specific question about why this or that C construct is translated to different assembler or similar stuff, please open a new question where you describe precisely which technicallity you don't understand.

Comment: I'm in agreement. Asking this type of question on OS may be asking too much due to its generality. Now that I'm starting to "get it", I don't see any harm in closing the post. Sorry about that!

Comment: My first assembler experience was staring at compiled ZX Spectrum Basic code, wondering why it was so much slower than "real games". It looked like your left side code; I soon got the knack of saving everything in registers and ending up with something like your right side code. In fact, I can read that code *better* than the left side; it's line by line equivalent to your C.